# While downloading I get an error

Tags: miktex, installing

While downloading MiKTeX downloading was not achieved and I get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder (2)\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe" --update-fndb --admin --log-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder (2)\miktex\config\uninst.log" --verbose:
Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Souhayla\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Souhayla\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder (2)")...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder (2)\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe" --force --mklinks --admin --log-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder (2)\miktex\config\uninst.log" --verbose:
Making format links...
Making script links...

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Souhayla/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
  source line: 308
  message: The operation failed for some reason.
  info: C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder (2)\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe
```

What should I do?

Comment: Make sure you completely delete (not just uninstall) the old installation.

Comment: Do you have all the admin privileges you need to install the programme?

Comment: Check what is working. Quite often only fc-cache is not executed successfully and this is only needed for xelatex and can be done later again. So open update and package managers and try out a small pdflatex document.