# MiKTeX won't typeset

Tags: miktex

I have just bought a new computer and downloaded MiKTeX onto it. When I try to typeset some of my old TeXworks files I get:

```
"Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Stephen/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Stephen/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help."
```

The log file tells me:

```
2015-09-02 14:56:13,339+0100 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2015-09-02 14:56:13,537+0100 FATAL texify - The operation failed for some reason.
2015-09-02 14:56:13,538+0100 FATAL texify - Info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe
2015-09-02 14:56:13,538+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2015-09-02 14:56:13,538+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 290
```

When trying to download new packages or open MiKTeX update (Admin) I get an error saying:

> MiKTeX Problem Report Message: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

Please could someone help me?

Stephen

-edit- Problem solved, see below

Comment: At first, don't do first tests with texify. Use pdflatex, at best on a small document on the command line.  If this fails too: Open the package manager (admin), use repositories -> synchronize, and then check if all packages starting with miktex are installed. Then open the update manager (admin) and check if there are updates.

Comment: [While downloading I get an error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264280/35864) seems to have a similar problem. Maybe some MikTeX package is corrupted. We probably just have to wait a bit until a fixed version is pushed to the repositories.

Comment: @moewe: I don't think that is the same problem. The one is a (probably harmless) error at the end of the installation, this here is an error while trying to compile.

Comment: @ulrike There were some miktex packages that hadn't been installed, mainly language specific ones, but I got an error: MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: TeXWorks has nothing to to with MikTeX. In the LaTeX world the editor and the LaTeX the formatter are completely separate entities. You can use TeXWorks as an text editor even with having LaTeX installed.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any other miktex program running when opening the package manager / installing packages / updating.

Comment: @ulrike Installing the other packages worked, thank you very much!!

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex

Comment: Possibly related: [MiKTeX: Two things did not succeed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265674/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problems were solved when I followed this comment by Ulrike Fischer:

> Open the package manager (admin), use repositories -> synchronize, and then check if all packages starting with miktex are installed

After I installed the miktex files, it compiled perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, I keep getting the same error message as before, the ones in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me as MikTeX threw different errors, so I uninstalled and instead installed TeXLive. I tried to compile and it said something to the effect of

> `Can not create file foo.pdf`

So I went to delete foo.pdf and it said something to the effect of

> `Can not delete. File locked by foo.pdf.old.old`

I did a quick Ctrl+Alt+Del and there were no MikTeX processes running. Vim was open, but I don't see why that would have affected a pdf file. In any case, I restarted the computer and it worked fine.

Before uninstalling MiKTeX, try deleting your PDF file

Answer (score 1):

You need to run TeXworks as administrator and you'll be able to both compile as well as install packages on the fly again.

Comment: Thank you!
True, I guess my "solution" is more of a work-around than a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to MiKTeX Settings (Admin) > General tab > Update Formats. You'll be prompted on every missing files, so install them all.

Comment: Not only the formats have to been updated, all packages!  Package **manager** has to be called to be sure all installed packages are up to date and to see, if there are new packages available ...