# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed

Tags: errors, miktex

Earlier I posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266606/lzma-decoder-error).  I *finally* found an installer that seemed to work.  Now I have the TeXworks icon on my desktop.  So I ran it on a `.tex` file.  I got this console output:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Yarb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Yarb/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

----

I went to that log file and found this:

----

2015-09-10 18:28:20,953-0500 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database<br>
2015-09-10 18:28:20,999-0500 FATAL texify - The operation failed for some reason.<br>
2015-09-10 18:28:20,999-0500 FATAL texify - Info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe<br>
2015-09-10 18:28:20,999-0500 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp<br>
2015-09-10 18:28:20,999-0500 FATAL texify - Line: 290<br>
2015-09-10 18:29:56,841-0500 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database<br>
2015-09-10 18:29:56,884-0500 FATAL texify - The operation failed for some reason.<br>
2015-09-10 18:29:56,884-0500 FATAL texify - Info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe<br>
2015-09-10 18:29:56,884-0500 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp<br>
2015-09-10 18:29:56,884-0500 FATAL texify - Line: 290<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:00,495-0500 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:00,544-0500 FATAL texify - The operation failed for some reason.<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:00,545-0500 FATAL texify - Info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:00,545-0500 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:00,545-0500 FATAL texify - Line: 290
2015-09-10 18:30:43,457-0500 INFO  texify - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:43,503-0500 FATAL texify - The operation failed for some reason.<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:43,503-0500 FATAL texify - Info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:43,503-0500 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp<br>
2015-09-10 18:30:43,503-0500 FATAL texify - Line: 290
```

Comment: The installer version does not necessarily come with the newest packages and fixes, that is why the installation pages states at the top: "When you have installed MiKTeX, it is recommended that you run the update wizard in order to get the latest updates." So please try an update, for that to properly work you should have TeXworks and all other TeX-based programmes closed. See [Update MiKTeX 2.9](http://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex) and [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864)

Comment: Awesome! This is now a duplicate of [MiKTeX: Two things did not succeed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265674/35864) and it was resolved by an update. So I will vote to close as a duplicate.