# Can not install MikTex

Tags: miktex

I tried to install MikTeX a number of times but still not able to do, always comes to the end then an error pops up. Below there is the log file for the installation.

```
initializing setup service...
starting installer...
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Temp\mik23791
visiting repository C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Temp\mik23791...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 988a4b83024c02f8f95fdf68e1a944bb
going to install 10673 file(s) (215 package(s))
extracting files from ae.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amscls.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsfonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from amsmath.tar.lzma...
extracting files from asymptote.tar.lzma...
extracting files from avantgar.cab...
extracting files from babel.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from babel-spanish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex8bit.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bibtex8bit-polish.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bidi.tar.lzma...
extracting files from bookman.cab...
extracting files from carlisle.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cbcoptic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from chktex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from courier.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cweb.tar.lzma...
extracting files from cyrillic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dehyph-exptl.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from elhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from enctex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from etex-pkg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from euenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from eurosym.tar.lzma...
extracting files from float.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontname.tar.lzma...
extracting files from fontspec.tar.lzma...
extracting files from geometry.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ghostscript.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-cfg.tar.lzma...
extracting files from graphics-def.tar.lzma...
extracting files from gsftopk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from helvetic.cab...
extracting files from hyperref.tar.lzma...
extracting files from hyph-utf8.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ifxetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from jknappen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-lib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from knuth-local.tar.lzma...
extracting files from latex-fonts.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lm.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ltxmisc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lua-alt-getopt.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luainputenc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from lualibs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luamplib.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luaotfload.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatexbase.tar.lzma...
extracting files from luatextra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from makeindex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mflogo-font.tar.lzma...
extracting files from mfware.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-arctrl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-asymptote-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-autosp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-axohelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibarts-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-biber-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-bzip2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cairo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-chktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cjkutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-config-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-console-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-curl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-cweb-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-devnag-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-english.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-french.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dict-german.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-doc-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvicopy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipdfmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvipng-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvips-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-epstopdf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-etex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-expat-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-findtexmf-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fontconfig-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fonts-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-freetype2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-fribidixetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gd-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ghostscript-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-graphite2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gregorio-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-gsf2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-harfbuzz-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-hunspell-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-icu-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-int-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-jpeg-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-kpathsea-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lacheck-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-latex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-libressl-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-log4cxx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua52-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lua53-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-luatex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-lzma-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-m-tx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-makeindex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-md5-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metafont-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mfware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-misc.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mkfntmap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mktex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mo-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpfr-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mpmcli-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mspack-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mthelp-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-mtprint-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-omega-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pdftex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pixman-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-pmx-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-png-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-poppler-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-popt-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-posix-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-potrace-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ps2pk-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-psutils-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-qt5-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-runtime-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tdsutil-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-teckit-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex2xindy-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-tex4ht-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texify-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texware-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-texworks-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ttf2pk2-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-ucrt-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-uriparser-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-vc140-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-web-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xetex-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-xindy-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-yap-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zip-bin-x64.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zlib-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from miktex-zzip-bin-x64-2.9.tar.lzma...
extracting files from multirow.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ncntrsbk.cab...
extracting files from oberdiek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from palatino.cab...
extracting files from pdftex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from plain.tar.lzma...
extracting files from polyglossia.tar.lzma...
extracting files from poppler.tar.lzma...
extracting files from pslatex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psnfss.cab...
extracting files from pstricks.tar.lzma...
extracting files from psutils.tar.lzma...
extracting files from rsfs.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ruhyphen.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from tex-ini-files.tar.lzma...
extracting files from texinfo.tar.lzma...
extracting files from thumbpdf.tar.lzma...
extracting files from times.cab...
extracting files from tools.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ttf2pk.tar.lzma...
extracting files from ukrhyph.tar.lzma...
extracting files from unicode-data.tar.lzma...
extracting files from utopia.cab...
extracting files from xetex.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xgreek.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xindy.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xkeyval.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xltxtra.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xunicode.tar.lzma...
extracting files from xypic.tar.lzma...
extracting files from zapfchan.cab...
extracting files from zapfding.cab...
extracting files from zerohyph.tar.lzma...
updating package definition directory ("C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
installed 3281 package definition files
visiting repository C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Temp\mik23791...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
initexmf "--user-install=C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9" "--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=0 "--log-file=C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --disable-installer --verbose:
MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Info: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\MemoryMappedFile\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
Line: 159

>Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
 You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 166
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="C:\Users\Nabeel\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is the OS that you use? There are the basic version and the complete version: https://miktex.org/download.

Comment: @Sebastiano Windows 10

Comment: Are you using the basic? With W10, sometimes, there are some problems.

Comment: Yes I am using the Basic

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265674/miktex-two-things-did-not-succeed

Comment: I use the full version but with OS W7 without problems. Net Installer 64-bit: you can download all packages and install a complete TeX/LaTeX system on Windows.

Comment: Also consider the portable version. If that doesn't install, then the problem is deep.