# TeXMaker compiles without error but pdf does not change

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, texmaker, document-configuration

I installed MiKTeX 1.2 (MiKTeX 22.3) and TeXMaker 5.0.2 winX64. I used overleaf before but now I cannot find what is the problem here.

When I run the project (which correctly works on my friend's computer) there are no errors, but the pdf is not updated. I installed the same versions and the same packages from the other computer on mine, but it remains the same. Also same problem on TeXworks. I use Quick build and + view pdf is on in configuration. pdflatex is also installed in the path.

I only found the following line in C:\Users\KeyvanNajarian\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log:

"Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed."

Can anyone give me a hint, how to solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265674/47927 ? I don't know whether this bug still exists though. Did you close the PDF before compilation?

Comment: try to compile a small example on the command line.

Comment: When you say that the PDF is not updated, do you mean 1. An opened PDF, in reader, is not dynamically updated; or, 2. If you close the PDF reader, then re-open it, there is no change? If the first, it may be that your system cannot communicate between TeX and the PDF reader.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I Installed MiKTeX and Texmaker with Admin settings again. In MiKTeX admin mode I went to Settings,Format and pushed "build format" for the pdflatex, after this, I opened the Texmaker with admin rights, at this point when I wanted to compile, it worked. For my project I got pop up windows to install more packages. Now I can generate the pdf, though only with admin rights. Unfortunately I cannot clarify the problem better than this, appreciate it if someone can.