# PDF compiling goes wrong

Tags: compiling

I am using MikTeX, When I run the file, it does not update the pdf anymore. 
The console output ends with:

```
Sorry, but "C:\Users\SMRS.LUSTRUM\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/SMRS.LUSTRUM/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

The Errors, Warnings, badboxes tab does not show any error.

Anyone had the same problem or knows a solution

Comment: What does the content of `C:/Users/SMRS.LUSTRUM/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log` has to say?

Comment: texify (and pdftexify) is rather picky and often reports that something didn't work even if there wasn't really a problem. I never use it but always call pdflatex and the other tools I need directly. If you want a more automatic processing check arara.

Comment: I was using pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTeX and solved the problem with the answer from Guilherme Z. Santos. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should be using `pdflatex`. I belive this issue was approached in this question ([MiKTeX won't typeset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264374/miktex-wont-typeset)): *Open the package manager (admin), use repositories -> synchronize, and then check if all packages starting with miktex are installed. Then open the update manager (admin) and check if there are updates.*

Comment: @SimonMoreels Since this answer solved your problem you should upvote it and accept it. That's a better way to thank the answerer than your comment on the question.

Comment: The problem came back, now all packages starting with miktex are installed. Still no errors, but no compiling . .

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex`?