# MiKTeX Configuration Utility failed

Tags: errors, miktex

I've run a MiKTeX update today and then, as usual, I've run `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats` in MiKTeX Settings (MiKTeX Options).

The problem is that the latter gives the error: `The MiKTeX Configuration Utility failed` while it is creating the format file for LaTeX2e.

The transcript says:

```
Creating the etex format file...

Sorry, but makefmt did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
```

The `initexmf.log` says:

```
2016-11-06 10:05:40,276+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:05:40,348+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2016-11-06 10:05:40,880+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:05:40,896+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=etex --no-dump etex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 10:05:41,365+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2016-11-06 10:05:41,365+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", arguments="--engine=pdftex --dest-name=etex --no-dump etex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer", exitCode="1"
2016-11-06 10:05:41,365+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2016-11-06 10:05:41,365+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 159
2016-11-06 10:05:53,137+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:05:53,159+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=latex --no-dump latex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 10:05:53,307+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2016-11-06 10:05:53,307+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", arguments="--engine=pdftex --dest-name=latex --no-dump latex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer", exitCode="1"
2016-11-06 10:05:53,307+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2016-11-06 10:05:53,307+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 159
2016-11-06 10:05:59,799+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:05:59,815+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makebase.exe --dest-name=mf --no-dump mf.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 10:06:00,884+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:06:00,915+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdfetex --no-dump pdfetex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 10:06:01,216+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2016-11-06 10:06:01,216+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", arguments="--engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdfetex --no-dump pdfetex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer", exitCode="1"
2016-11-06 10:06:01,216+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2016-11-06 10:06:01,216+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 159
2016-11-06 10:06:05,115+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:06:05,130+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 10:06:05,284+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2016-11-06 10:06:05,284+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", arguments="--engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer", exitCode="1"
2016-11-06 10:06:05,284+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2016-11-06 10:06:05,284+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 159
2016-11-06 10:06:08,899+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:06:08,930+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdftex --no-dump pdftex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 10:06:09,084+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2016-11-06 10:06:09,084+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", arguments="--engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdftex --no-dump pdftex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer", exitCode="1"
2016-11-06 10:06:09,084+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2016-11-06 10:06:09,084+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 159
2016-11-06 10:06:13,729+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 10:06:13,745+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=tex --dest-name=tex --no-dump tex.ini --verbose --enable-installer'
```

The `miktex-makefmt.log` says:

```
2016-11-06 10:06:01,185+0100 INFO  makex - Creating the pdfetex format file...
2016-11-06 10:06:05,246+0100 INFO  makex - Creating the pdflatex format file...
2016-11-06 10:06:09,046+0100 INFO  makex - Creating the pdftex format file...
2016-11-06 10:06:14,029+0100 INFO  makex - Creating the tex format file...
2016-11-06 10:06:14,045+0100 INFO  makex - Running miktex-tex.exe...
```

I've tried also to synchronize the repository in MiKTeX Package Manager, after checking that all packages starting with `miktex` were installed, as indicated for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264374/miktex-wont-typeset), and then re-run everything but without success.

I've visited the MiKTeX project page, I don't know is [this notice](https://miktex.org/alert/package-refactoring-2016-11) is related to the problem.

However, my documents still compile without problems.

EDIT: this is what I get tring to build `etex` manually:

`initexmf.log`:

```
2016-11-06 15:05:14,369+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-11-06 15:05:14,401+0100 INFO  initexmf - running 'miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=etex --no-dump etex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer'
2016-11-06 15:05:14,785+0100 FATAL initexmf - The executed process did not succeed.
2016-11-06 15:05:14,785+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-makefmt.exe", arguments="--engine=pdftex --dest-name=etex --no-dump etex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --verbose --enable-installer", exitCode="1"
2016-11-06 15:05:14,785+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2016-11-06 15:05:14,785+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 159
```

`miktex-makefmt.log`:

```
2016-11-06 15:05:14,689+0100 INFO  makex - Creating the etex format file...
```

Comment: I can't currently update so I can't run tests. Go to miktex settings, tab formats and try to build one of the failing formats (e.g. etex) manually so that you get a better error message.

Comment: Dont you get some tex log in the build dialog?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `Creating the etex format file...
Sorry, but makefmt did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-makefmt.log
You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is the message I get, I don't know where to find other logs...

Comment: The `initexmf.log` entry looks like it might be the same as https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2542/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a MiKTeK bug and they've solved it now, see [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2542/).

Today I've run another update plus `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats`.

The first time `Update Formats` gave me an error and the transcript said more details than before (sorry, I haven't copied it) but from the second time onwards the error hasn't appeared any longer.

P.S. = should I delete my question?